# How to zoom image on mouseover at some XY coordinate?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I display set of images(small). I need to show the larger image(300*300) at some XY co-ordinate when mouseover event occurs on an image while mousout larger image has to disappear . Please give some solution.

Comment: `mouseover` is an event which you can only hook with under each Javascript. Since Javascript runs at the client side, it does not see any piece of JSF source code. It instead only sees the HTML DOM tree of the HTML source as generated by JSF. In other words, JSF is completely irrelevant in this question. To reach a wider audience (HTML/Javascript) on your question, I strongly recommend to edit, retag and reformulate the question based on the JSF-generated HTML output. Start with a HTML `<img>` element and a Javascript function and once you get it to work, port it back into the JSF source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thus actually want an [image map](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+javascript+image+map). Since I've never used this I can't tell the details from top of head, but the link should help you further. You can for example make use of [HTML `<map>` and `<area>` elements](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_image_maps.asp), or go ahead with a [pure CSS](http://www.frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap/) approach.

There is no standard JSF component which can represent the `<map>` and `<area>` elements. The Sun JSF tutorial however (by coincidence) covers a [custom component example](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnavm.html) with which you can represent them using pure JSF.

Comment: Hello BalusC, the links you have given will be useful in some other day.But My requirement is exactly the same as in http://www.cardsdirect.com/petite-chrsitmas-cards.aspx. Instead of showing the larger image near to small image, I need to display bigger image in a fixed position for all and it should be at top by hiding the components at that place. I hope explained clearly..